# NoSuchMethod Error while using Exposed with H2

Tags: kotlin, h2, kotlin-exposed

I'm trying to used exposed and h2 for storage inside a ktor server.

After setting up an in memory connection with `Database.connect("jdbc:h2:mem:test", driver = "org.h2.Driver")`

Whenever I try to read/write to the database I get the following error:

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
> org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.getSettings()Lorg/h2/jdbc/JdbcConnection$Settings;
> at org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.vendors.H2Kt.isMySQLMode(H2.kt:17)

My build.gradle.kts contains the following:

```
implementation("com.h2database", "h2", "1.4.197")
implementation("org.jetbrains.exposed", "exposed-core", "0.24.1")
implementation("org.jetbrains.exposed", "exposed-dao", "0.24.1")
implementation("org.jetbrains.exposed", "exposed-jdbc", "0.24.1")
```

Any ideas?

Comment: If should be fixed together with this issue: https://github.com/JetBrains/Exposed/issues/919

Comment: Old code uses internal class from H2 that exists only in H2 1.4.199 and H2 1.4.200, but doesn't exist in older versions and in the upcoming next version.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by Evgenij Ryazanov in the comments above, turns out this is an issue with my the combination of versions i'm using.

As a temporary fix I've updated my H2 version to 1.4.200